# inequality in a shape of inclusion exclusion formula

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, inequalities

I have two inequalities to show, both of which describe some probabilities. First I know how to handle, and it follows from applying arithmetic-harmonic mean inequality:

consider 9 numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_2,b_3,c_1,c_2,c_3$, sum of $a$'s is at most 1, and the same with $b$ and $c$.
first inequality is
$\sum_{i\neq j\neq k \in \{1,2,3\}} \frac{a_ib_jc_k}{3- b_i - c_i - a_j - c_j - a_k - b_k}\left( \frac{2}{2-b_k-c_j}+  \frac{2}{2-a_k-c_i} + \frac{2}{2-a_j-b_i}\right) \leq (a_1+a_2+a_3)(b_1+b_2+b_3)(c_1+c_2+c_3)$

The second I don't know how to show yet. I've written a program checking it for all possible configurations of numbers, and it seems like it also should be true.
Still, I don't know how to get a hold on it because here i have terms once negative and once positive and thus i cannot use AM-HM anymore to split terms nicely. 
Can someone point me to similar inequalities that resemble the inclusion exclusion formula? Any help would be much appreciated.
Here's the inequality:
$1-\sum a_i -\sum b_j -\sum c_k + \sum_{i\neq j \in\{1,2,3\}} \frac{2a_ib_j}{2-b_i - a_j} +  \sum_{j\neq k \in\{1,2,3\}} \frac{2b_jc_k}{2-c_j - b_k} +  \sum_{i\neq k \in\{1,2,3\}} \frac{2a_ic_k}{2-c_i - a_k} - \sum_{i\neq j\neq k \in \{1,2,3\}} \frac{a_ib_jc_k}{3- b_i - c_i - a_j - c_j - a_k - b_k}\left( \frac{2}{2-b_k-c_j}+  \frac{2}{2-a_k-c_i} + \frac{2}{2-a_j-b_i}\right) \leq (1-a_1-a_2-a_3)(1-b_1-b_2-b_3)(1-c_1-c_2-c_3)$

Comment: Is this research or math competition?

Comment: research. inequality comes from trying to prove negative correlation of three 0-1 random variables. I would be glad even to see some references that might resemble the second inequality. so far googling inequalities + inclusion exclusion didn't give anything that could give me a hold on this

Comment: If you reformulate it in terms of polynomial inequalities,  this can be solved by computer algebra if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Here is an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities

Comment: That's very interesting Per. could you point me to some resource that would outline the method?

Comment: Max: it's not Bonferroni type because we don't cut it, we have full enumeration up to $n$

Comment: You don't say that the variables are nonnegative but you assume that, right?

Comment: yes, they are non-negative. there's even one more assumption that one can make: if you take row $r\in \{1,2,3\}$ then $b_r + c_r \leq 1- (a_1+a_2+a_3)$ and symmetrically when swapping $a,b,c$. however this i don't know if is crucial for showing, what might happen is just that LHS will be negative